# Float image left, float text right and align at bottom?

Tags: html, css, image

I basically have three elements on two rows- a logo (image 350px wide by 150px tall)and a text heading in the first row, and then a navigation bar on the next.  What I am trying to do is make the text align with the bottom of the image, while having the image in the far left and the text on the far right.  I was able to get it in the right position by using position: relative & position: absolute, but since I am trying to make the website responsive when it shrinks down the text and logo overlap and it breaks.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
This is what I am trying to make-->>>

```
------------------------------------------------------
logo x x x
logo x x x
logo x x x                                  text here
------------------------------------------------------
     navigation bar navigation bar navigation bar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using `inline-block` using CSS. Just wrap everything inside one parent element.

```
.container-element {
  /* some fixed width */
  width:1000px;
}

.image-element,
.text-element {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}

.image-element {
  width:600px;
}

.text-element {
  text-align:right;
  width:400px;
}

.nav-element {
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<div class="container-element">
  <div class="image-element">
    <img src="..." />
  </div>
  <div class="text-element">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="nav-element">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am still having some problems.  Since I want it to be responsive, when I shrink down the size, the text doesn't stay in the window (because of the fixed width).  Anyway around this?

Comment: Yeah. Use percentages on the inner elements and remove the fixed with for the outer element.

Comment: Ughhh. This is driving me crazy haha.  Now that I switched to percentages, when I shrink down the size the layout breaks and the heading is overlapping the logo completely.  Any more ideas?